# jquery not getting data attribute value from html form

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, laravel-5.1

I am working on laravel 5.1 and backbone.js. On underscore template, I have placed `data-id` attribute with dynamically generated value. I am trying to get data value but I get "undefined" error. Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-xs-10 p-r-0 comment-user-detail">
<span class="user-name"><%- loggedInUserName %></span>
<p class="more">
    <%= comment.message %></p>
<br>
<ul class="comment_inner" data-id="<%- comment.id %>">
    <li class="fbcommentlike"><a href="#">Like</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Reply</a></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>1</li>
    <li><span class="comment_date_time"><%= moment(comment.created_time.date , 'YYYY-MM-DD
        h:m:s').format("DD MMMM") %></span> at <span class="comment_date_time"><%= moment(comment.created_time.date
            , 'YYYY-MM-DD h:m:s').format("h:m") %></span></li>
</ul>
<% }); %> </span>
</div>
```

Here is my jquery code:

```
console.log  $(this).attr('data-id')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
console.log($(this).data('id'));
```

Comment: If that was the problem I'm pretty sure they'd get a SyntaxError and not an "undefined" error. (`console.log $(this).attr('data-id')` is valid CoffeeScript).

Comment: But the standard way of accessing data attributes is using data function. read more here: https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Using `.attr` to access a property will still not throw an "undefined" error.

Comment: Then the issue is with the selector. $(this) will not be the element having that data attribute.